# phpmyadmin - stacked charts broken

Tags: mysql, charts, phpmyadmin, pchart

In phpmyadmin 4.2.2 and 4.0.4, I cannot recreate three column stacked charts as per the documentation:
http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Charts#Three_columns

```
SELECT
  225       AS 'Amount',
  'Tele2'   AS 'Operator',
  '2009-11' AS 'Month' UNION
SELECT  653, 'Omnitel', '2009-11' UNION
SELECT 1157,   'Tele2', '2009-12' UNION
SELECT  855, 'Omnitel', '2009-12' UNION
SELECT  569,   'Tele2', '2010-01' UNION
SELECT  253, 'Omnitel', '2010-01' UNION
SELECT  282,   'Tele2', '2010-02' UNION
SELECT  455, 'Omnitel', '2010-02' UNION
SELECT 2960,   'Tele2', '2010-03' UNION
SELECT 3552, 'Omnitel', '2010-03'
```

Is suppose to return this:
[image: three column correct]

However, this is what I get: ("Series" setting, which is obscured in the image below, is set to "Amount")
[image: broken chart] No possible configuration of Stacked enabled/disabled or X-axis as 'operator' creates the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of data that needs to be fed for charts has since been changed. The data should be in the format `<x-axis, series1-value, series2-value,..>` rather than old format `<x-axis, series-name, value>`.

I've raised a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1527/) requesting support for old format as well.
The wiki page is outdated. I've raise a [bug ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4431/) for that as well.

Try with

```
SELECT 
    '2009-11' AS 'Month',
    225 AS 'Tele2',
    653 AS 'Omnitel'    UNION
SELECT  '2009-12', 1157,  855   UNION
SELECT  '2010-01',  569,  253   UNION
SELECT  '2010-02',  282,  455   UNION
SELECT  '2010-03', 2960, 3552
```

Comment: Perfect! Generated the stacked chart no problem. Thank you.